# selecting a location with minimum distance from a particular LatLng object android

Tags: android, google-maps

While working on an application with google map integrtaion.I have 2 classes `RoutesData,LocationDistances` and an activity class in which I am implementing a method `getOverAllRoute()` to select a LatLng object in list returned from a method in RoutesData class, with minimum distance from a particular LatLng object.

```
public class RoutesData{
...
...
public ArrayList<LatLng> allRoutePoints(){
        ArrayList<LatLng> allPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>(Arrays.asList(
                //icPoints
                new LatLng(33.582752, 73.044503),
                new LatLng(33.595504, 73.050912),
                //station
                new LatLng(33.601097, 73.047798),
                new LatLng(33.598755, 73.055607),
                .. .
                . . 
    ));
        return allPoints;
    }



public class LocationDistances {
    LatLng locs;
    double distances;

}




public void getOverAllRoute(){
        RoutesData rD = new RoutesData();
        ArrayList<LatLng> mainRoutePoints = rD.allRoutePoints();
        LocationDistances srcLocDis = new LocationDistances(); //to store location + distances from source
        ArrayList<LocationDistances> srcLocDisList = new ArrayList();
        //convert source latlng to location obj
        Location srcLoc = new Location("");
        srcLoc.setLatitude(dll.latitude);
        srcLoc.setLongitude(dll.longitude);
        // to compare distances from source location
        for(int i =0;i<mainRoutePoints.size();i++){
            Location mainPointsLoc = new Location("");
            mainPointsLoc.setLatitude(mainRoutePoints.get(i).latitude);
            mainPointsLoc.setLongitude(mainRoutePoints.get(i).longitude);
            //store distances and location in arraylist
            srcLocDis.locs = mainRoutePoints.get(i);
            srcLocDis.distances = srcLoc.distanceTo(mainPointsLoc);
            srcLocDisList.add(srcLocDis);

        }
        LocationDistances min=null;
        for(LocationDistances x:srcLocDisList){
            min=(min==null||x.distances<min.distances)?x:min;
            Log.d("LocDist:",Double.toString(x.distances));
        }
        srcStartMin=min.locs;
        Toast.makeText(this,srcStartMin.latitude+" "+srcStartMin.longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

But my application crashes as I call the getOverAllRoutes() method from my menu item.

Comment: What is the error when the app crashes? On which line does it crash? You say something about doing getOverAllRoutes() from a menu item, is this correctly initialized (don't see any code about a menu)

Comment: yup its correctly initialized actually when i place another method into menu it runs well. all it seems a problem with my getOverALLRoutes Logic :(

Comment: post your logcat with crashes

Answer (score 0):

i have suspicion it has to do with

```
srcLoc.setLatitude(dll.latitude);
srcLoc.setLongitude(dll.longitude);
```

because i don't see that initialized